# Failed to resolve: androidx

Tags: androidx

I came back to my android project to finish working on it and  All of sudden I'm getting this error message saying

"Failed to resolve androidxAffected modules: < a href="openFile:D:/mobile app/pro/project/app/build.gradle">app < /a > "

"ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx. Affected Modules: app"

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"androidx.activity_home.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.4"

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.activity_home:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.activity_home.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'
}
```

Comment: Connecting to VPN solved the issue for me - there was an issue with my dns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it should work

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha03'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha03'
```

Comment: I posted this answer because Android recommends to use androidx for these libraries

Comment: I see, good to know, I switched to your code and it works thank you